# Unable to download scoped repos in Nexus

Tags: npm, nexus

I have a containerized Nexus3 repo `v 3.43.0-01` that I've successfully published a package to:

[image]

However, when attempting to download this package via `npm i`,

I receive the following error[image]

This is a scoped repo, defined as `"@my-scope/tinymce": "4.1.0"`

The only thing I've been able to find so far is that it's probably due to the encoded slash in the scope, but that appears to have been fixed since 3.17. I'm not running through a proxy, it's just a local container. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A workaround could be to use npm-group repo in nexus, that contain one hosted nexus repo with your private (scoped) depenedencies, and another proxy repo to registry.npmjs.org. Then configure your private package without the scope "@" and publish to the private hosted nexus repo.

Then from the other projects that want to use this private dependency, put in the .npmrc the registry of the "group" **(for example registry=http://localhost:8395/repository/npm-group/)** with the credentials for the nexus repo. Then all dependencies public and private should come without any problem, just be sure to save your private dependencies without scope.